# Any idea how to do custom supportedCookingModes in Alexa discovery?

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to return a Discovery Response, but the [supportedCookingModes](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/cooking-property-schemas.html#cooking-mode) only seems to accept standard values and only in the format of ["OFF","BAKE"], not Custom values as indicated by the [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/cooking-property-schemas.html#cooking-mode). Any idea on how to specify custom values?

```
{
    "event": {
        "header": {
            "namespace": "Alexa.Discovery",
            "name": "Discover.Response",
            "payloadVersion": "3",
            "messageId": "asdf"
        },
        "payload": {
            "endpoints": [
                {
                    "endpointId": "asdf",
                    "capabilities": [
                        {
                            "type": "AlexaInterface",
                            "interface": "Alexa.Cooking",
                            "version": "3",
                            "properties": {
                                "supported": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "cookingMode"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "proactivelyReported": true,
                                "retrievable": true,
                                "nonControllable": false
                            },
                            "configuration": {
                                "supportsRemoteStart": true,
                                "supportedCookingModes": [
                                    {
                                        "value": "OFF"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "BAKE"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "CUSTOM",
                                        "customName": "FANCY_NANCY_MODE"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you are missing comma after "BAKE". Can it be the problem?

Comment: No, I was simplifying the example code and stripped out the other modes. I get a different error if there's a syntax problem in the JSON. Updated the example code. I wonder now if Custom modes only work if you are using an MCS (Multi-Capability Skill)?

Comment: What exactly is the error that you are getting?

Comment: No error, discovery just fails

Answer (score 2):

Custom cooking modes are brand specific. This functionality is not yet publicly available. I recommend you to choose one of the existing cooking modes:
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/cooking-property-schemas.html#cooking-mode-values